# Meteor subscribe multiple publication in single line

Tags: meteor

My question is simple. I am subscribe multiple publication in `onCreated`. How can I make in single line?

```
Template.Name.onCreated(() => {
  Template.instance().subscribe('countries');
  Template.instance().subscribe('pincode');
});
```

Something like

```
Template.Name.onCreated(() => {
  Template.instance().subscribe(['countries','pincode']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanna create a combined publication

```
Meteor.publish('combined', functinon() {
    return [
        Countries.find(),
        Pincodes.find()
    ];
})
```

and then subscribe to that

```
Template.Name.onCreated(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('combined');
});
```

Comment: No. In my case I may use `pincodes` for other templates. I need to combine in subscription not in publication.

Comment: Well, you can still have that as a separate publication. Why would you need to put it on one line anyway?

Comment: I don't think there'd be any performance benefits of doing so, but if you find a way, let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

`['countries','pincode'].forEach(x => {Template.instance().subscribe(x);});`

Though I agree with @durrrr, there is not going to be any performance benefit.  I'd leave it as two separate lines myself.